# Angular 2 canActivate async

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a service which checks does user has permissions to open route.

```
@Injectable()
export class GuardService implements CanActivate{
     user: User;
     constructor(private _userService: UserService) {
}

canActivate(): any{
    return this._userService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
        if(user.user_type == 'admin'){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

But the problem is that it never passes. The problem is in this observable but I don't know how to handle it. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Return an `Observable` instead of a `Subscription` by changing `subscribe` to `map`

```ts
canActivate(): any{
    return this._userService.getUser().map(user => {
        if(user.user_type == 'admin'){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }); // <<== added
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just change subscribe to map because subscribe have no first() method. Edit it, and I will approve the answer ;)

Comment: Right. Thanks, missed that one.

Comment: `subscribe` won't work here at all. The router needs to be able to subscribe. `With `map` you might not need `first`. I think this was changed a while back (not sure).